Separate differents agents at the end of a conveyor for differents sink
I've used the model "ConveyEnter" available on the Cloud to model the entry of two different agents into the circuit, at the exit I'd like the pallets to go out via a Sink and the Sheets via robot transport, unfortunately the robot always carries the assembly.
To do this I used a Split at the end of the first conveyor to separate the elements, the following Image shows the circuit


The Split block literally splits individual agents.
What you want is to send some to sink and other to sink1. For that, you should use the SelectOutput block instead, with the correct condition as needed to divide the flow.

My problem is that both agents are coming at the same time as one agent but i need to split it into to differents parts again and the robot should pick only the Sheet. Using the SelectOutput funktion, Anylogic is giving me always the same error "Unresolved compilation problem: Sheet cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Consider the Batch/Unbatch blocks instead
